# How to load nested JSON data into Snowflake?

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, snowflake-stage

Here's my table schema.

```
create or replace TABLE xxxx.yyyy.EVENTS (
    EVENT_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9),
    EVENT_NAME VARCHAR(16777216),
    EVENT_PARAMS VARIANT,
);
```

And here's my data.

```
{
  "event_timestamp": "2023-06-15T10:16:14.41358+00:00",
  "event_name": "click",
  "event_params": [
    { "key": "link_classes", "value": { "string_value": "c-button" } },
    { "key": "link_url", "value": { "string_value": "javascript:void(0)" } },
    { "key": "outbound", "value": { "string_value": "true" } }
  ]
}
```

Trying to load this data directly using a command similar to this.

```
COPY INTO xxxx.yyyy..EVENTS
     FROM 'gcs://my-data-source'
     STORAGE_INTEGRATION = my_integration;
```

I receive an error that column count doesn't match. The field `event_params` should be loaded into VARIANT but doesn't seem to happen automatically. How to approach this?

Thanks

Comment: [Transforming Data During a Load](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-transform) - section: [Load semi-structured Data into Separate Columns](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-transform#load-semi-structured-data-into-separate-columns)

Comment: You need to specify in your `COPY` command which column to insert into. Also, why not insert in the entire JSON payload in one `VARIANT` column then transform...